# best way to hack replace_na_if in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Short of a `replace_na_if` verb, what's the best way to systematically replace NAs in all character/numeric/logical/etc... columns with the same value? Here's what I do now.

BEFORE

```
starwars %>% 
  # islolate the columns for the post
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  filter(!complete.cases(.))

# A tibble: 51 x 3
   height  mass birth_year
    <int> <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     97    32         NA
 2    180    NA         64
 3    180   110         NA
 4    150    NA         48
 5     NA    NA         NA
 6    160    68         NA
 7    191    90         NA
 8    170    NA         91
 9    224    82         NA
10    206    NA         NA
# ... with 41 more rows
```

AFTER

```
starwars %>% 
  # isolate the columns for the post
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  filter(!complete.cases(.)) %>% 
  replace_na(as.list(
    setNames(rep(0, sum(map_chr(., class) == "numeric")),
             colnames(.)[map_chr(., class) == "numeric"])))

# A tibble: 51 x 3
   height  mass birth_year
    <int> <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     97    32          0
 2    180     0         64
 3    180   110          0
 4    150     0         48
 5     NA     0          0
 6    160    68          0
 7    191    90          0
 8    170     0         91
 9    224    82          0
10    206     0          0
# ... with 41 more rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `mutate_if` and `ifelse` to achieve this:

```
library(dplyr)
starwars %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)))
```

You may use also tidyr::replace_na too, but you'd need to provide a list of columns and its filled values though:

```
library(tidyr)
replace_ls <- starwars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% names() %>% 
  sapply( function(x) 0, USE.NAMES=TRUE) %>% 
  as.list()

replace_na(starwars, replace_ls)
```

Comment: yea, good point. meant to post the `mutate_if` idea as an option. btw, you should check out `purrr`! also, would prefer to stay in the pipe for the whole operation.

Comment: `mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)))` also works. I think this solution or your are sufficiently "tidy."

Answer (score 0):

Because `is.na` has a data.frame method, it's as simple as

```
starwars[is.na(starwars)] <- 0
```

Comment: right, trying not the break the pipe. also this does not solve the selective replacement on column class.

Comment: Selecting columns is clearly a solved problem from your post. Incorporating this into a pipe is an exercise left for the reader.

Comment: you are right that I have a working solution. I was looking for something more elegant that does not require breaking the pipe. the solution offered by LmW. was a good one. your solution is something I do frequently but does not address the selective replacement on column class. classy move on the downvote.